# How to get only month name and total in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-queryset

I am trying to get only month name and count number from

```py
Data = QuerySet [{'month': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Dhaka' +06+6:00:00 STD>), 'count': 2 }]
```

If I use `Data[0]['month']` result is showing like `(2021, 3, 1,0,0, ...)` but I need to see only as March

How can I view the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming getting the total/count is not a big issue here.

Since you already have the datetime object ie.: (2021, 3, 1,0,0, ...) , you can extract the Month name using obj.strftime("%B")

Like this:

```
>>> date_obj
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Dhaka' LMT+6:02:00 STD>)
>>> month = date_obj.strftime("%B")
>>> month
'March'
```

You can also get short version of months, weekdays etc : [Python documentation: strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But while i run  **month = data.strftime("%B")** The Error is `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'strftime' `  . For your information, i already ` import datetime `

Comment: did you save the result of Data[0]['month'] in date_obj?

Comment: You are right, i missed it. Well after saving result of `Data[0]['month'] ` , i got `2021-03-01 00:00:00+06:00` full as a result. My present code is **m = (data[0]['month'])
        m.strftime("%B")
        print(m)**  what can i do now please?

Comment: I got the right answer. What i did, is `m = (data[0]['month']).strftime("%B")` in one-line, now it's giving the answer as **March** . Thank you so much.

Comment: np!.. i assumed you might have saved the datetime obj so i didnt mention that in the response